# Retrieve readable text from raw PDF data

Tags: python, pdf

I'm currently coding an app that takes data from one PDF file, processes that data, and then copies it into another file. I use PyPDF to read, write, and merge data from one PDF to another.

My problem arises when the PDF I'm using contains special characters that distort my raw data like this.

*What I want*

```
/Span <</MCID 0/Lang (fr-FR)>> BDC q
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re
W* n
BT
/F1 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 247.85 760.66 Tm
/GS10 gs
0 g
/GS11 gs
0 G
[(th)14(is)-3( is)11(a)9(n exem)10(ple)-4(!)] TJ
ET
Q
q
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re
W* n
BT
/F2 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 318.41 760.66 Tm
0 g
0 G
[( )] TJ
```

`*What I have*

```
/Span <</MCID 0/Lang (fr-FR)>> BDC q
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re
W* n
BT
/F1 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 247.85 760.66 Tm
/GS10 gs
0 g
/GS11 gs
0 G
[<0004>14<0068>-3<002F0064>11<0012>9<004B>10<0057>-4<002F001C0068005A>] TJ
ET
Q
q
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re
W* n
BT
/F2 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 318.41 760.66 Tm
0 g
0 G
[( )] TJ
```

*==texts in this exemple above are not related==*

My main code looks like this :

```py
reader = PdfReader(self.file_in)
        for page in tqdm(reader.pages, desc="Processing pages",  total=len(reader.pages)):

             contents = page.get_contents()
             data = contents.get_data()
                
                    
             raw_data = data.decode("latin-1")

             result = self.__process_raw_data(raw_data)
              
                    

             encoded_data = result.encode("latin-1")
             contents.set_data(encoded_data)
             page.replace_contents(contents)

             new_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(width=page.mediabox.width,height=page.mediabox.height)
             new_page.merge_page(page)

             self.__class_writer.add_page(new_page)
```

where __process_raw_data browses into data and changes
`[(th)14(is)-3( is)11(a)9(n exem)10(ple)-4(!)] TJ` into
`[(th)14(is)-3( is)11(a)9(n ####)10(###)-4(!)] TJ` based on a blacklist.

I wonder if there's a way to translate that weird looking-text into a more readable treatable one ?

I first tried to decode them in hexa, then I tested other decoders such as utf-8, utf-16. I tried to link each character to the code it created, and that's how I noticed that they were characters generated by the font.

After that, I tried to replace all the fonts in the pdf file without destroying the positions, images or other formatting data. But the libraries I used (pikepdf, fitz, pypdf) didn't allow me to keep the overall look of the pdf.

I need this data to be readable before passing it to my __process_raw_data function, even if it means replacing the font with another one.

Comment: When processing content streams of PDFs, you have to deal with the strings therein having arbitrary encodings. The encodings depends on the current font when the string is processed. And a single character code in such an encoding does not necessarily correspond to a single "readable" character. Essentially instead of hoping for some normalization into your readable form you should improve your `__process_raw_data` method to properly parse the instructions, keep track of the current font, and process each string according to the encoding of that current font.

Comment: Also please be aware that replacing glyphs may not be possible if the font in question does not include the replacement glyphs. Furthermore, replacing glyphs may damage the layout of your text and result in overlapping texts or gaps.